# Solving a differential equation in terms of Green's function

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, greens-function

Suppose $$y''+a^2 y=f(x), y(0)=y(1), y'(0)=y'(1).$$

By integration by parts and some evaluations we end up with $$ y = \int_o^x (x-z)f(z)dz - a^2 \int_0^x (x-z)y(z)dz + c x + d. $$

But I am not able to eliminate the constants $c$ and $d$ using the boundary conditions. We have been given that final solution turns out to be $$ y(x) = \int_0^1 \frac{\cos(a(0.5-|x-z|))}{\sin(0.5a)} f(z) dz. $$

Any steps of hints are appreciated!

Comment: You can derive $c$ and $d$ in terms of $y'(1)=y'(0), y(0)=y(1)$ by differentiating the expression for $y$ using Liebniz integral rule.

I.e. $y'(0)=c$, $y(0)=d$.

After this, probably what you'd want to do is differentiate the expression again to get $y''$. You can substitute $y''(0)+a^2 y(0)=f(0)$ and $y''(1)+a^2 y(1)=f(1)$ which will tell you what $y(0)$ and $y(1)$ are.

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst "You can derive $c$ and $d$ in terms of $y'(1)=y'(0),y(0)=y(1)$": I am getting an expression for $c$ but not for $d$!

Comment: $d$ is just $y(0)$

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst "After this, probably what you'd want to do is differentiate the expression again to get $y''$.": Won't this just be the original ODE?

Comment: yep it will, well spotted.

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst So, how would we get $y(0)$ and $y(1)$ from the final step you suggested?

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst My question was, how do we get $y''(0)$ in the first place eventually to find $y(0)$?

Comment: the answer to this question is we can't find $y''(0)$ here, sorry my mistake!

Comment: You can just straight up find Greens function here and set this as the solution.

To do this we find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the ODE.

I.e. $y''+(a^2-\lambda)y=0$.
(linear 2nd order ODE).
Solve this and find the constants of integration using the boundary conditions.
Then:
$G(x,S) = \Psi_1(x)\Psi_1(S)/\lambda_1+\Psi_2(x)\Psi_2(x)/\lambda_2$
and the solution is $y(x) = \int G(x,s)f(s)ds$

(See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function#Finding_Green's_functions)

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst "Solve this and find the constants of integration using the boundary conditions.": A general solution would be $y=p \sin(\sqrt{a^2-\lambda} x) + q \cos(\sqrt{a^2-\lambda} x)$. I am still not able to find $p$ and $q$ using the boundary conditions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that for some linear operator $L$, the Green's function $G(x,s)$ is the function satisfying $LG(x,s)=\delta(x-s)$, and that $y(x)=\int_0^1f(s)G(x,s)ds$. For $Ly=y''+a^2y$, we have that $LG(x,s)=\frac{\partial^2 G(x,s)}{\partial x^2} + a^2G(x,s)=\delta(x-s)$.

We first obtain the solution 
$$
G(x,s)=
\begin{cases}
c_1(s)\cos(ax)+c_2(s)\sin(ax), \quad x<s \\ \\
d_1(s)\cos(ax)+d_2(s)\sin(ax), \quad x>s.
\end{cases}
$$

Although the constants are not explicitly functions of $s$, they are implicitly determined by the $s$ parameter of the Green's function and where the solutions are valid.

Applying the boundary conditions yields first that
$$c_1(s)=d_1(s)\cos(a)+d_2(s)\sin(a)$$
$$c_2(s)=d_2(s)\cos(a)-d_1(s)\sin(a)$$
Finally, we apply continuity and the Green's function criterion. Continuity first requires that
$$d_2(s)=d_1(s)\frac{\cos(0.5a)-1}{\sin(0.5a)}$$
The Green's function criterion requires a jump discontinuity of magnitude 1 at
$x=s$ such that
$$\frac{\partial G(x-s)}{\partial x}|_{x=s+}-\frac{\partial G(x-s)}{\partial x}|_{x=s-}=1$$ and from this we can reconstitute
$$
G(x,s)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{\cos(0.5a+a(s-x))}{\sin(0.5a)}, \quad x<s \\
\frac{\cos(0.5a+a(s-x))}{\sin(0.5a)}, \quad x>s.
\end{cases}
$$

With the Green's function at hand we may now write the solution to be $$y(x)=\int_0^1f(s)G(x,s)ds=\int_0^1f(s)\frac{\cos(0.5a-a|x-s|)}{\sin(0.5a)}ds$$
as required.